# Добавление библиотеки подлючения к PostgreSQL в Azure App Service

Tags: php, postgresql, azure

Здравствуйте! Есть проблема с подключением из App Service к серверу PostgreSQL, до этого приложение работало на MySQL и все работало, было решено перейти именно на постргрес и после этого с App Service начались проблемы. Сначала было перерыто кучу ресурсов для выяснения как подключить соответствующие расширения PHP (прямого доступа к php.ini нет, поэтому пришлось делать через параметры AppSettings) но это мало помогло, теперь ошибка другого рода и как её решить пока не могу сообразить:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\ext\php_pgsql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\ext\php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

т.е. надо подключить теперь непосредственно к web (предположительно IIS) модуль работы с postgresql, но как это сделать? На сервере Apache это решается подключением в файле конфигурации библиотеки libpq.dll.

Comment: Из описания не понятно, а библиотеки то сами были залиты или только конфигурация поменяна?

Comment: да. библиотеки лежат по указанному пути, поэтому то и ругается что пытается их загрузить по линии php но не может найти модуль работы с ними на стороне вэб сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько методов что бы подключить сторонние библиотеке к App Service. Либо как вы через App Settings, либо через ini-settings. Попробуйте другой метод.

Для того, что бы подключить расширения для PHP в App Services через ini-settings необходимо создать папку 'ext' в директории "d:\home\site". Затем в эту папку необходимо залить DLLки совместимые с выбранной версией PHP. После этого в App Setting надо добавить ключ "PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR" со значением "d:\home\site\ini" и создать в папке "d:\home\site\ini" файл с названием "extensions.ini". В файле extensions.ini можно декларировать расширения точно так же как это делается в файле php.ini. К примеру

```
; Enable Extensions
postgres=d:\home\site\ext\php_pgsql.dll
postgresspdo=d:\home\site\ext\php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

После данных танцев с бубном необходимо перезапустить Azure Website.

Данная последовательность является по сути переводом 
[официальной документации](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/#how-to-enable-extensions-in-the-default-php-runtime)

Comment: И так делал тоже, ошибка такая же. Документацию проштудировал несколько раз. т.е. подозрение именно в том что php не может работать с этими библиотеками из за отсутствия модулей работы с ними именно в настройках вэб сервера.

Comment: Иногда в Azure бывают просто необъяснимые баги. Если вы всё делаете по инструкции, попробуйте задеплоить проект в другой App Service. Просто лишь что бы исключить, что это проблема именно в Azure. У меня бывало такое с рназными компонентами данной платформы.

Comment: Попробовал по последнему рецепту из офф документации, там координальный вариант, скинуть всю папку php в bin и при запуске пхп файлов брать полностью свой пхп  --»»   From the Settings blade select Application Settings and scroll to the Handler mappings section. Add *.php to the Extension field and add the path to the php-cgi.exe executable. If you put your PHP runtime in the bin directory in the root of you application, the path will be D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe.   и все равно результат ошибка.

Comment: А на локальной машине всё работает и без ошибок? Как-то странно, что 3 разных метода и не работают.

Comment: на локальной все в идеале, причем локально веб страничка коннектится к постгрес серверу в azure, все работает без нареканий.